# How to display Woocommerce Product gallery image in collapsible

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, gallery

I have setup woocommerce store. In my store every product have more then 16 gallery images.

So i want to show first 8 gallery images then below show one link "See more sample configuration" on click collapsible event work and then below show another 8 gallery images. See this screen shot -> http://nimb.ws/2buKoh

For this my requirements i do research on google but can't find any solutions. So any one know solutions then please help me.

Thanks,
Ketan.

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Before posting, you are expected to research your issue and ***make a good attempt to write the code yourself***. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include ***a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)***.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jquery code.You need to add this jQuery into your theme option of bellow the wp_footer() in footer.php

```
<script type="application/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.images').append('<div id="loadMore">See more sample configuration</div><div id="showLess">Hide</div>');
    jQuery(".thumbnails a").hide();

    size_li = jQuery(".thumbnails a").size();
    x=3;
    jQuery('.thumbnails a:lt('+x+')').show();
    jQuery('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+3 : size_li;
        jQuery('.thumbnails a:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    jQuery('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-3;
        jQuery('.thumbnails a').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

after added the code, go to your product page and click on **See more sample configuration**.Try this then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your replay but sorry above code not working on store front woocommerce theme.